# Extending linear regression line to entire width of graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot seem to figure out how to get the linear regression line (aka line of best fit) to span the entire width of the graph. It seems to just go up the the furthest data point on the left and the furthest data point on the right, and no further.  How would I fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.interpolate import *
import MySQLdb

# connect to MySQL database
def mysql_select_all():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                           user='root',
                           passwd='XXXXX',
                           db='world')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = """
        SELECT
            GNP, Population
        FROM
            country
        WHERE
            Name LIKE 'United States'
                OR Name LIKE 'Canada'
                OR Name LIKE 'United Kingdom'
                OR Name LIKE 'Russia'
                OR Name LIKE 'Germany'
                OR Name LIKE 'Poland'
                OR Name LIKE 'Italy'
                OR Name LIKE 'China'
                OR Name LIKE 'India'
                OR Name LIKE 'Japan'
                OR Name LIKE 'Brazil';
    """

    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    list_x = []
    list_y = []

    for row in result:
        list_x.append(('%r' % (row[0],)))

    for row in result:
        list_y.append(('%r' % (row[1],)))

    list_x = list(map(float, list_x))
    list_y = list(map(float, list_y))

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))

    p1 = np.polyfit(list_x, list_y, 1)          # this line refers to line of regression

    ax1.xaxis.labelpad = 50
    ax1.yaxis.labelpad = 50

    plt.plot(list_x, np.polyval(p1,list_x),'r-') # this refers to line of regression  
    plt.scatter(list_x, list_y, color = 'darkgreen', s = 100)
    plt.xlabel("GNP (US dollars)", fontsize=30)
    plt.ylabel("Population(in billions)", fontsize=30)
    plt.xticks([1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000, 6000000, 
                7000000, 8000000, 9000000],  rotation=45, fontsize=14)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=14)

    plt.show()
    cursor.close()

mysql_select_all()
```

Comment: evaluate your polynomial at larger and smaller values of `x`?

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: `plt.plot([little_x, big_x], np.polyval(p1, [little_x, big_x]),'r-') `

Comment: little_x, big_x... are those arbitrary numbers or are you talking min x value max x value?

Comment: They are whatever span you want the line to encompass.

Comment: This problem is somehow much harder than it might seem on first sight. I marked this as duplicate because in the linked question answers are more generally applicable.

Comment: Indeed. It appears to be a duplicate. Most people with this problem will search "linear regression" or "line of best fit." As I did. The title is too far off of the other post. You'd need to do quite a bit of digging to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySQLdb` is not installed on my system so I can't run your code as such but the following lines of code should definitely work.

**EDIT** based on the comments: You additionally have to set the x-limits

```
x_low = 0.9*min(list_x)
x_high = 1.1*max(list_x)
x_extended = np.linspace(x_low, x_high, 100)

p1 = np.polyfit(list_x, list_y, 1)             # this line refers to line of regression

ax1.xaxis.labelpad = 50
ax1.yaxis.labelpad = 50

plt.plot(x_extended, np.polyval(p1,x_extended),'r-')   # this line refers to line of regression
plt.xlim(x_low, h_high)
```

Comment: It still showed the same thing

Comment: @NickT: Try `x_extended = np.linspace(500000, 10000000, 100)` and let me know

Comment: I tried that. It just changed the axis labels

Comment: @NickT: What is the minimum and maximum x value in your data?

Comment: min is 151697, max is 8510700

Comment: So even if you use `x_extended = np.linspace(15000, 10510700, 100)`, you dont see any extension?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didnt extend

Comment: Try adding plt.xlim(15000, 10510700) and check if you see something. May be the axis isn't extended. Unfortunately I can't run your code

Comment: Yes!!!!!! That last thing did it. Bazingaa, thanks!

Comment: @NickT: Glad to help. You are welcome.

Comment: Yeah shouldnt you edit the answer to include that?

Comment: @NickT: I already did ;)

Comment: @NickT: Do 0.9 and 1.1 work for you after setting the limits? If yes, then I leave my answer unchanged for x_low and x_high

Comment: I think this would work only in cases where none of the x data are negative. Also it somehow assumes that the line is angled such that it would first hit the vertical spines rather than the horizontal ones.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't include the data, here is a simple example using some artificial data.
The idea here is to find what the value of the regression line would be at the x-limits of your plot, and then force matplotlib not to add the normal 'buffer' at the edges of the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 1.8, 3.3, 3.5, 5.5, 6.1]
y = [1, 2.1, 3.0, 3.7, 5.2, 6.4]

p1 = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

plt.scatter(x, y)
xlims = plt.xlim()
x.insert(0, xlims[0])
y.insert(0, np.polyval(p1, xlims[0]))
x.append(xlims[1])
y.append(np.polyval(p1, xlims[1]))
plt.plot(x, np.polyval(p1,x), 'r-', linewidth = 1.5)
plt.xlim(xlims)
plt.show()
```

Without extending the regression line the sample data looks like 
[image: Before extending regression line]

And after extending,

[image: After extending regression line]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your plot to not extend past your data in the x-axis, simply do the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(x=0)
# Don't use plt.plot
ax.plot(list_x, np.polyval(p1,list_x),'r-')
ax.scatter(list_x, list_y, color = 'darkgreen', s = 100)
ax.set_xlabel("GNP (US dollars)", fontsize=30)
ax.set_ylabel("Population(in billions)", fontsize=30)
ax.set_xticks([1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000, 6000000, 7000000, 8000000, 9000000],  rotation=45, fontsize=14)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=14)
```